# How to Create custom Session wrapper class in .net core and access out side of contrller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core-2.0, session-state

I implement .net core application. and I need to implement session in .net core in a session wrapper class. so, can you give a proper solution for this?

I tried multiple ways, but I can't access the session outside of the controller or common class.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and where you want to access the session?

Answer (score 0):

1. you nee to use IHttpContextAccessor. Create class and interfae something like this :

**

```
public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public SessionManager(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void SetSomeName(string name)
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

            httpContext.Session.SetString("Name", name);
        }
    }
```

**

2. configure those services in startup.cs :
   `services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`
    `services.AddTransient<ISessionManager, SessionManager>();`
3. You are good to go.